# Difference between "so" and "and so"

Tags: grammar

- He was ill **and so** he was rejected.
- He was ill **so** he was rejected.

Which of the above sentences is correct?

Both version mean the same, don't they?

Comment: I would say that neither was incorrect, but there is no particular reason to include _and_.

Comment: For me, "and so" seems to provide fluidity but technically both are correct.

Comment: ... Yes, 'fluidity' ... 'so' is rather abrupt, clinical, depersonalised. Matter-of-fact. Heading for dismissive. _If they can't be healthy they’d better be rejected, and not add to the malingering workforce problem._ [vaguely after Scrooge.]

Comment: Sometimes you just need an extra syllable to make things come out right. That explains a great deal about optional deletions of _that, who, to, is,_ and numerous other short function words. Those are the questions about "Which one is correct"? with the answers "They're all correct" , which constitute a large proportion of the questions here.

Answer (score 2):

The word *so* (in the relevant sense) is a connective adverb, but it has a number of properties that make it behave more like a coordinator (i.e. a coordinating conjunction).

In these respects, *so* behaves like an ordinary connective adverb:

1. It can be used to link a subordinate clause to a main clause, as in "The mill could be sold off, so providing much-needed capital."
2. It can be used in combination with another coordinator, namely *and,* as in "This may make the task seem easier and so increase self-confidence."

But in these respects, it behaves like a coordinator:

4. It often occurs *without* another coordinator, as in "There was a bus strike on, so we had to go by taxi."
5. It occurs at the start of the clause containing it. "The scandal intensified, so he had to resign" is acceptable, but *"The scandal intensified, he so had to resign" is not.
6. In certain rare cases, it can link, not just main clauses, but also finite verb phrases, as in "He wanted to avoid the rush-hour so took the early train," and adjectives, as in "It was an untried, so rather risky, undertaking." Note that it can't join non-finite verb phrases, which is why, in the example in (2) above, the "and" is mandatory.

Because of property (2), "He was ill and so he was rejected" is correct. Because of property (4), "He was ill, so he was rejected" is also correct. Normally, when a coordination does not have a coordinator, the coordinates after the first one have to be preceded by a comma. The fact that *so* only partly behaves like a coordinator likely explains why a comma would typically be used in "He was ill, so he was rejected," whereas no comma is needed in "He was ill and so he was rejected."

(My source for the above is [Huddleston & Pullum (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), pp. 1319-1320 and 1739, though I've presented things in a slightly different order.)

Comment: Just to make explicit a subtle point: both "he wanted to avoid the rush-hour so took the early train" and "he wanted to avoid the rush-hour, so he took the early train" are grammatically correct. The OP's given pair of sentences are also both correct once a comma is duly inserted in the second sentence.

Answer (score 1):

In English, the word "and" is a conjunction. Its basic function is to combine two separate things, such as to combine two or more objects: "The sheep and the pigs are in the pen", or to join two separate but related clauses: "The sheep are in the pasture and the pigs are in the pen."

In English, the punctuation mark "comma" can also take on this role: "The sheep, the pigs are in the pen," is technically grammatically correct (though hard to read) as is "The sheep are in the pasture, the pigs are in the pen," (though I like a semicolon better in this case).

So to your example, what happens if we replace the "and" with a comma?

- (Original) He was ill and so he was rejected.
- (Comma) He was ill, so he was rejected.

Now compare this to your second example without a conjunction:

- He was ill so he was rejected.

Without the conjunction to join the two ideas, the sentence is awkward. Your readers may subconsciously insert a comma as they read it in order to pacify that awkwardness. But this may be an area where the English language is currently shifting, with the "and" being reduced to a comma and eventually being dropped entirely.

But why is the second example awkward without a conjunction? Because the sentence expresses two separate and distinct ideas: "He was ill" and "he was rejected". The word "so" joins these two ideas causally (the same as "therefore"), but does not have the grammatical function of a conjunction and so (hyuck) does *not* join the two ideas syntactically.

I stumbled upon your question as I was researching the exact same question for myself. I have not found any source that identifies a semantic difference between ", so" and "and so". As far as I can tell, the meaning is the same with the primary difference being the type of conjunction used to connect the before and after clauses grammatically. I would, however, suggest that no conjunction at all (no comma and no "and") is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I disagree with this. The word "so" is also a conjunction, just like "and". And look at the following usage example from the Cambridge dictionary: "I was lost so I bought a street map."

Comment: @Rastapopoulos - That example is exactly the same (grammatically) as my example "he was ill so he was rejected" - the "so" functions to demonstrate a cause and effect relationship. It connects the clauses causally, but not functionally. Compare "I was lost and I bought a street map", which has a completely different meaning. I also mention in my answer that English may be shifting away from "and so" to just "so". Linguistic shift is a common occurrence. Usage will also vary geographically; Wiktionary describes the use of a comma alongside "so" as "chiefly North American", and Cambridge is UK.

Comment: If speaking it would be natural to pause before "so" (in my opinion at least), so it makes sense to include a comma. If you feel there wouldn't be a pause, then omit it.

Comment: @StuartF - Commas don't always signify a pause. They're used to separate clauses or lists, or to join unrelated ideas. When used as a conjunction or conjunctive adverb, a comma can serve the same function in writing that a pause serves in speaking (as in this sentence). But when speaking you don't pause at every comma when itemizing your grocery list. The simple explanation of "comma = pause" we're taught in grade school is just not complete. (But it is serviceable. Combined with learned intuition, it gets most writing 80-90% accurate, even if people don't fully understand why.)